# Does Nesbot Carbon error with trailing data and not with "too little" data?

Tags: sql-server, laravel, php-carbon

I'm looking to confirm a theory of mine, but I really need to be sure first.

I have laravel 5.0 and SQL Server 2012.

when I have fields with the default datetime, I can't insert values with more than 3 microsecond spaces because the database errors out.

So if I set it to `datetime2(3)` I can insert a lot more microsecond spaces but only the first ones will be preserved that fit in the field.

If I set it the SQL Server grammar to `'Y-m-d H:i:s.u'` it will try to insert a number with 6 spaces every time.

What i'm looking for is that carbon will not have issues with the fact that the database will return less than 6 numbers(namely the 3) and will continue to work properly in all cases without exceptions when I call a toArray() in laravel or something like that.

I can't do datetime2(7) because carbon then complains about trailing data.

**So in short**

Does carbon, with set dateformat `Y-m-d H:i:s.u`, gladly always accept a number with only 3 decimal place points, and happily insert a 6 decimal point into the database and not object that the database only saves up to 3 points?

Comment: I'd love to know what you found out - did you test it? Can you provide an update? I just migrated a Laravel app to Azure SQL that had a lot of existing data and am dealing with the "trailing data" error right now. How are you making it work?

Comment: ah, right. make your fields datetime2(3), and then use the .u format for carbon. that'll solve a lot. it's the solution I went with, and the datetime2 field is a lot less picky than datetime was.

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people looking into this issue:

I'm using datetime2(3) data fields in the database, and I use the `Y-m-d H:i:s.u` date notation without issue now for the last 2 months, even with all the wonky date stuff I sometimes throw at it, I've had no issues.

Only issues I had when I accidentally used `datetime` or `datetime2(7)`